# Formula or Filter for Data Pull

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, populate

I have data in one sheet that I want to pull into a second sheet based on ID numbers.

I have added a link to my example google sheet and i'm hoping someone may be able to help, i'm a novice when it comes to these things and rather than individually go through tons of data line by line I was hoping there was an easier way to populate the data.

[Link to Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tCgFiBjAA8_-eWs4hmOTUwOHwKzyuizrWtUYDzZ6SFc/edit#gid=483192699)

So for example I have a table like this in Sheet 1:

**|ID Number|  Vehicle Type|   Wrap|   Branding|**

6906
6902
4600
5342

in Sheet 2, I have the same but the vehicle type, wrap and branding are populated, like so:

**|ID No|   Vehicle Type|   Wrap|   Branding|**

|6906| ---Hybrid --- | -Blue | ---50----|

I want to pull the data from Sheet 2 and populate Sheet 1.
In this example there are only 4 entries but the actual data I have to trawl has thousands of entries and the second sheet has ID numbers but in different orders.

How would be the best way to tackle this? Hope that all makes sense?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: your sheet is private.

Comment: I thought i'd made it public, does it allow you to request access?

Comment: yes but it's best practice to make it viewable, or better, editable by anyone. If you don't want to expose your email you can create an [anonymous sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform) and paste the data there.

Answer (score 0):

*Here's a generalized approach based on your description, this single array-style lookup formula goes into `Cell_B2` of **Sheet1 tab** & pulls the data from **Sheet2** accordingly based on `ID No.`*

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,xlookup(Σ,Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!B:D,))))
```

[image]

Comment: I think he wants the opposite. Lookup Vehicle Type, Wrap, Branding and return corresponding ID No.

Comment: well... oops my bad then!!